# What do I need to see the database file in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

ALL,
I wrote a simple android app that uses database.
When I execute it everything is OK. However when I switch the phone to mount mode I can't find the actual *.db file.
I am trying to execute following:

cd /media/
find . -name *.db

I also tried to search for the database file without success.

After playing a little with SQLite database browser I know that I need to save the file after creation.

Is there such a function in Android API?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If your app uses a database, it will be placed in the `/data/data/<your-apps-package-name>/databases` directory on your phone.  To see it on the phone, I believe you need root privileges.

You should be able to pull the database locally to a connected machine which has `adb` installed on it.  Or you can use `ddms` with Eclipse to pull the data to your machine.

Comment: Hi, No I won't be able to pull anything as I can't see the file itself on the device. It just not present. Any idea how to see the file?

Comment: As I stated in my answer, you will need root privileges to see it on the phone.  Rooting your device has some risk involved, and I would not recommend doing it if you are afraid of 'bricking' your phone.  There are a lot of things you can do wrong with a rooted device if you are not careful.

Comment: Nicholas, are you saying that I won't be able to see the file with the simple "ls -la" unless I am a root on the phone? Personally I don't believe it. FTM, Android says that you can copy the database over to you host, and I'm saying that I can't do that as I specifically can't see anything with the simple "ls -la".

Comment: Also I don't want to become "root" on the phone, but AFAIU I should be able to see the file with "700" privileges. Am I wrong?